# Unity - If I create two scripts with its own Start() method, which one will call first?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lifecycle

I created two simple scripts (ScriptA and ScriptB). Both contained Start() method.
I found that the later one always started first. Is it the normal way of Unity to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html):

> By default, the Awake, OnEnable and Update functions of different
>   scripts are called in the order the scripts are loaded (which is
>   arbitrary). However, it is possible to modify this order using the
>   Script Execution Order settings (menu: Edit > Project Settings >
>   Script Execution Order).